# Как сделать кликабельной ссылку в теге <details>?

Tags: html, ссылка

Как сделать кликабельной ссылку на "Первый класс" ? Сейчас при клике на нее - открывается список с предметами, а должен осуществляться переход на другую страницу.

Список с предметами должен открываться при клике на значок + рядом с "Первый класс", а не при клике на текст.

```
<details>
<summary>Первый класс</summary>
<a href="/оценки/математика/">Математика</a>
<a href="/оценки/русский_язык/">Русский язык</a>
<a href="/оценки/английский_язык/">Английский язык</a>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил разделить "Первый класс" и `details`, а в `summary` как раз поставить этот плюсик. Ну и стилизовать как необходимо.

HTML

```
<div class= "main">
  <a class="title" href="#">Первый класс</a>
  <details>
    <summary>+</summary>
    <a href="/оценки/математика/">Математика</a>
    <a href="/оценки/русский_язык/">Русский язык</a>
    <a href="/оценки/английский_язык/">Английский язык</a>
  </details>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main {
  position: relative;
}

/* убираем стрелочку у details */
details > summary {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}
/********************/

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

details {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 110px;
}
```